# Broken links in locked question

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

I came across [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113198) thread, it's very interesting and has many views (400000+).

Many links given in the question are broken(`__missing__ items`, `List stepping`, `.pth files` and much more) and we cannot edit it since it's locked. Now since this question looks very popular, it'll be very useful if someone edit it to make it better.

What can be done for questions like this one?

Comment: That's the reason why that lock is a historical lock, and we don't allow questions like that anymore. Links do rot, and the community cannot possibly fix this problem in a timely and reliable way. Historical locks do emphasize that, but I believe the message is *Don't post questions like those anymore -- this is what finally happens to them, locked or not.*

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being a little dense, here (it's still early where I'm at), but what exactly do you mean by broken links? Each of the examples you list links straight to the appropriate answer, and none of those answers have external links in them. In fact, the only one with an issue, AFAICT, is [Unpacking+print() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#3267903).

Comment: Try to click on `__missing__ items`.. It does nothing.

Comment: Takes me to the answer that starts "From 2.5 onwards dicts have a special method `__missing__`...". Maybe an issue with your browser?

Comment: That's really weird.. I tried it from two different computers.. On linux using Chrome and still cannot go there.

Comment: @MarounMaroun,  That link just takes you to an answer further down on the page. Maybe it needs javascript ? Anyway it works fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is locked due to historical significance. It has been frozen in time, and much like an artifact being displayed at a museum,

1. any defects or oddities that were present at the time are preserved as is, and
2. it is not to be tampered with, only admired for a short while.

We generally don't support "hidden features" questions and questions that don't have one specific best or correct answer anymore, so there is nothing that needs to be done or that *can* be done.

Comment: Then... delete it?

Comment: "...only admired for a short while" Is 6 years really considered a "short while"?

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: As you quoted, it's "admired for a short while", not "displayed at a museum for a short while". Unless you're saying you made a trip to the museum to stare at the same exhibit for 6 years...