# Should I update a rotten link in a closed post?

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks, locked-posts

[This off-topic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769443/41222) has a broken link to Google Code. I'd like to replace the broken link with one to [GitHub](https://github.com/zepouet/Xee-xCode-4.5/blob/master/XeePhotoshopLoader.m#L108), but the question has been locked, so I can't edit it.

It appears that the [usual solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278667/41222) is to leave it frozen in time, defects at all, but I don't think that's a responsible thing to do here. I didn't find this post by looking for it here; I found it by [searching for the phrase on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=psd+is+not+my+favorite+format). We have a lot of Google juice, and our old and broken stuff is going to rank highly in searches of the broader Internet.

What's the best thing to do here?

Comment: That particular question is locked; you couldn't even edit the answer if you wanted to.

Comment: I agree with fixing things in general. If something adds sufficient value to be not deleted, then let's improve it if we notice substantive changes. However this is a not a serious thread, so... `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

The key question is, does it add value?

In the particular case you linked, it's an off-topic question ("What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?"). It's under a historical lock, and for good reason.
And the answer itself is essentially a rant against a specific file format. So, it doesn't add value. Even if it weren't locked, there would hardly be a point in editing this.

However, if you find something that *does* add value, editing might be appropriate. For example, replacing the link with the appropriate archive.org link.
Most of the time, these things don't add value - it's off-topic for a reason. The *very* rare times that they do, an edit is OK.

Alternatively, you could look for the part that is worth preserving, and create a self-answered question about that (possibly CW).
In the answer you linked, there's some talk about the byte alignment in the PSD file format. If this had addressed a specific pitfall when working with the PSD file format, it would be worth making a separate Q&A, to help other developers avoid that pitfall.

Comment: Since I came across this meta post, editing historically locked posts doesn't perform a bump and there's no real harm in making the change (keeping an attribution  or reference up to date) - in this case I've edited the answer with the new link.